# Deployed App responds slow after some time from heroku

Tags: heroku, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I had deployed my Google assistant app on Heroku before 3 month,which use Api.ai and heroku as a middle one.

Earlier,it was responding well and taking normal time to respond back to Google assistant,But now it takes some time and Google assistant  doesn't error on the another side.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see the [Tour] (again, because I see you already have [tag:Informed]), [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Right now, this question does not contain enough information for us to help at all.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the lack of Information I'm not sure if this addresses your case, but this is a common scenario when using Heroku (free):

Taken from [Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#dyno-sleeping):

> If an app has a web dyno, and that web dyno receives no traffic in a 30 minute period, the web dyno will sleep. 
>   [...]
>   If a sleeping web dyno receives web traffic, it will become active again after a **short delay**.

That means that the first request from api.ai (Dialogflow.com) to Heroku (after a while without traffic) is likely to time out, since the heroku dyno needs to wake up.